# How to detect if powerline is installed?

Tags: vim, powerline, vim-powerline

I have [powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/) installed on some of my computers, but not on others. I'd like my `.vimrc` to detect if it is installed before trying to load/enable the powerline package so I can avoid the errors that are generated.

**How can I detect if powerline is installed?**

I should note that I use [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) as my Vim package manager.

Answer (score 2):

I do not use powerline, but this is the generic method.

Assuming you using Vim's packages you move your extra plugins to be optional packages and then just use `:silent!` when doing `:packadd` in your `vimrc`.

```
silent! packadd other_plugin
```

Alternatively you can use `exists()` & `VimEnter` autocmd if you need something more complex.

```
augroup load_more
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * if exists(':SomeCommand') | packadd foo | endif
augroup END
```

NOTE: I do not use powerline so I do not know what commands or variables are provided to use. It could provide a custom `autocmd` event to simplify this or have some other method for loading related plugins.

For more help see:

```
:h exists()
:h VimEnter
:h :silent
:h packages
```

Comment: I should have added to my question that I use Vundle as my package manager. I've updated the question.